# Bash, grep - why is a command with a caret not working in a subshell?

Tags: bash, grep, special-characters, subshell

I'm trying to determine if a `git add` action has created any expected modifications, and the following works in an interactive shell

```
$ BASE_DIR=foo/bar/baz
$ git add "${BASE_DIR}"
$ git status --porcelain
M  foo/bar/baz/a.txt
M  foo/bar/baz/b.txt
$
$ git status --porcelain | grep "^M  ${BASE_DIR}"
$ echo $?
0
```

I want to write it in a script as

```
if $(git status --porcelain | grep "^M  ${BASE_DIR}"); then
  git commit -m "changes added"
  git push
fi
```

However, when moving the commands to a subshell, it fails:

```
$ if $(git status --porcelain | grep "^M  ${BASE_DIR}"); then echo true; fi
M: command not found
```

What's special about a caret within a subshell?

Answer (score 2):

(Publishing just because I had all the work to write the question and then noticed my error)

There's nothing special about a caret within the string. The command `$(git status --porcelain | grep "^M  ${BASE_DIR}")` is running the given test correctly and *capturing* the output of the subshell. This output (which looks like "M  foo/bar/baz/a.txt") is then *executed* when given as argument to `if`, explaining the error "M: command not found".

To fix it, drop the parenthesis and discard the output. The return value is that of the last command in the pipe.

```
if git status --porcelain | grep --quiet "^M  ${BASE_DIR}"; then ...
```

Comment: Note that `--quiet` is a GNUism.  `-q` is standard. Beware that it won't work properly if `$BASE_DIR` contains basic regexp operators (`.*\[^$`) and it could report a false positive on `foo/bar/bazic/whatever`.

Comment: With GNU `grep`, you can do `grep -qP "^M  \\Q$BASE_DIR\\E(\$|/)"` which should work as long as `$BASE_DIR` doesn't contain `\E` or newline characters.